# Sending emails with GAE and Ruby

Tags: ruby, email, google-app-engine

How can I send emails from a Ruby/Rails app using GAE Mail API? I see documentation for Python/Java/Go/PHP, but nothing for Ruby.

Comment: Why you want not use some gem for that? For example https://github.com/mikel/mail

Answer (score 3):

The documentation you saw is only for the standard environment. Sending emails natively (i.e. using the GAE infrastructure) is not supported for those languages in the flexible environment either. From the [Mail](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#mail) section of the [Migrating Services from the Standard Environment to the Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating) guide:

> The App Engine Mail service is not available outside the standard
>   environment. You will need to use a third-party mail provider such as
>   [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/), [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/), or [Mailjet](https://www.mailjet.com/) to send email. All of
>   these services offer APIs to send email from applications running
>   anywhere.
>
> The following guides show how to use these services with the flexible
>   environment:
>
> - [Sending emails with SendGrid](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/sending-emails-with-sendgrid)
> - [Sending emails with Mailgun](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/sending-emails-with-mailgun)
> - [Sending emails with Mailjet](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/sending-emails-with-mailjet)

So similarly you'd have to use one of those third party services. The referenced guides include Ruby examples.